# Update relative jumb label name during compile time in NSIS

Tags: installation, compilation, label, nsis

Is there a way to update Goto label each time during compile time in NSIS.

I have tried ${*Counter*} for labeling the conditions like below but no luck.

```
IntCmp $R2 1 succ${_Counter_}
${IF} $R2 != "1"
 Goto Error
${EndIf}
Goto end{_Counter_}
succ${_Counter_}:
DetailPrint "Success"
end{_Counter_}:
DetailPrint "End"

Error:
DetailPrint "Error"
```

Any approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!define /ReDef MyLbl ${__COUNTER__}
loop${MyLbl}:
  ...
  StrCmp $0 $something loop${MyLbl} end${MyLbl}
end${MyLbl}:
!undef MyLbl
```